# .cab creator for WinCE CF 2.0

Tags: compact-framework, cab

So I created a cab file in Visual Studio and it all was fine and dandy. i am using HP thin client with WinCE 4.0

One thing though, there is a folder called Program Files on My Device and there is a folder called Program Files on Hard Disk.

Now, My Device memory resets itself each time the machine is rebooted. 
Unfortunately, VS 2008 won't let me change the path for where the cab installs the program.

Any ideas on how to change the path?

Comment: essentially i want to change %InstallDir%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out: any time you wish to install an application in a different path, use Custom folder, not Programs or Program Files.

Looks like InstallDir can not be modified w/o hacks. I used Custom folder while in the Cab project and specified the path I wish to install this app; it worked.